# Java collection pack() method

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

What would be a good way to implement the `pack()` operation of a collection using Java stream?  Here is what I'd like to accomplish:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A");
List<List<String>> packs = items.stream().pack();
// packs:  [[A,A],[B,B],[A],[C,C],[A,A,A]]
```

Alternatively, the pack operation could return a list of tuples in the form of *(index, element, count)*:

```
[(0, A, 2), (2, B, 2), (4, A, 1), (5, C, 2), (7, A, 3)]
```

Currently I implemented this using a mutable accumulator in the following fashion:

```
Packer<String> packer = new Packer<>();
items.stream().forEach(packer);
List<Triple<Integer, T, Integer>> packs = packer.get();

public class Packer<T> implements Consumer<T>, Supplier<List<Triple<Integer, T, Integer>>>
{
    private List<Triple<Integer, T, AtomicInteger>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    private Optional<Triple<Integer, T, AtomicInteger>> currentElement = Optional.empty();
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void accept(T t)
    {
        if (currentElement.isPresent() && currentElement.get().getMiddle().equals(t))
        {
            currentElement.get().getRight().incrementAndGet();
        }
        else
        {
            currentElement = Optional.of(Triple.of(count, t, new AtomicInteger(1)));
            result.add(currentElement.get());
        }
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Triple<Integer, T, Integer>> get()
    {
        return result.stream().map(x -> Triple.of(x.getLeft(), x.getMiddle(), x.getRight().get())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Comment: You might get better answers to this kind of question at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `packer::accept` is redundant since it already implements `Consumer`.

Answer (score 4):

You can collapse adjacent elements with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
List<List<String>> packs = StreamEx.of(items)
        .collapse(Object::equals, Collectors.toList())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[[A, A], [B, B], [A], [C, C], [A, A, A]]
```

[**JDoodle Demo**](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/4W9)

I'm not sure if StreamEx supports collapsing with indexes.

Answer (score 3):

As @shmosel mentioned in his answer, it can done by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
List<List<String>> packs = StreamEx.of(items).collapse(Object::equals, Collectors.toList()).toList();
System.out.println(packs);
// [[A, A], [B, B], [A], [C, C], [A, A, A]]

MutableInt idx = MutableInt.of(0);
List<Triple<Integer, String, Integer>> packs2 = StreamEx.of(items).collapse(Object::equals, Collectors.toList())
        .map(l -> Triple.of(idx.getAndAdd(l.size()), l.get(0), l.size())).toList();

System.out.println(packs2);
// [[0, A, 2], [2, B, 2], [4, A, 1], [5, C, 2], [7, A, 3]]
```

[Update]: Just found out, actually there are even simpler APIs available in StreamEx for this OP:

```
packs = StreamEx.of(items).groupRuns(Object::equals).toList();
System.out.println(packs);

packs2 = StreamEx.of(items).runLengths().mapKeyValue((k, v) -> Triple.of(idx.getAndAdd(v.intValue()), k, v.intValue())).toList();
System.out.println(packs2);
```

Amazing!

Comment: Very clever! Though it should be noted that this may not work in parallel. Also, you can reuse `packs` to produce `packs2`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A");
List<List<String>> result = items.stream()
    .collect(() -> new LinkedList<List<String>>(),
        (list, e) -> {
            if (list.isEmpty() || !list.getLast().contains(e))
                list.add(new LinkedList<>());
            list.getLast().add(e);
        },
        (a, b) -> {});
System.out.println(result);
```

result

```
[[A, A], [B, B], [A], [C, C], [A, A, A]]
```

This can not be processed with parallel stream.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could create a custom collector for that:

```
  static class PackCollector<T> implements Collector<T, List<List<T>>, List<List<T>>> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<List<T>>> supplier() {
        return () -> {
            List<List<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(new ArrayList<>());
            return list;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<List<T>>, T> accumulator() {
        return (list, s) -> {
            int size = list.size();
            List<T> inner = list.get(size - 1);
            int innerSize = inner.size();
            if (innerSize > 0) {
                T last = inner.get(inner.size() - 1);
                if (s.equals(last)) {
                    inner.add(s);
                } else {
                    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                    newList.add(s);
                    list.add(newList);
                }
            } else {
                inner.add(s);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<List<T>>> combiner() {
        return (left, right) -> {

            List<T> lastLeft = left.get(left.size() - 1);
            List<T> firstRight = right.get(0);

            T leftElem = lastLeft.get(lastLeft.size() - 1);
            T rightElem = firstRight.get(firstRight.size() - 1);

            if (leftElem.equals(rightElem)) {
                lastLeft.addAll(right.remove(0));
            }

            left.addAll(right);

            return left;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH);
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<List<T>>, List<List<T>>> finisher() {
        return Function.identity();
    }

}
```

And then use it:

```
 List<List<String>> result = items.stream().parallel().collect(new PackCollector<>());
 System.out.println(result);
```